# I'm confused: can u-substitution help convert from Cartesian to Polar?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Just for fun, I decided to try one method of converting a parabola to polar coordinates. Without loss of generality and assuming $a \neq 0,$ let's suppose our quadratic $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ can be factored as

$$y(x) = a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$$

Now I notice that if our expression is of the form $u(u + c),$ it's easier to solve because we can then divide both sides. So, we make the substitution $u = x - r_1$ we end up with

$y(u + r_1) = au(u+r_1 - r_2),$ then if we convert to polar coordinates $y = r\sin(\theta),$ $u = r\cos(\theta)$ we can then divide both sides by $r \cos(\theta)$ to obtain

$\tan(\theta) = a(r \cos(\theta) + r_1 - r_2)$ which is then explicitly solvable for $r$ in terms of $\theta.$

But in going about this process, I'm confused as to how I "back-substitute" $u$ in terms of $x$ to complete the conversion process. Can $u$ substitution of this nature help simplify conversions to polar coordinates? Or is this concept flawed?

Comment: A _useful_ parameterization would take the turning point as the origin, but $y=ax^2$ is equivalent to $r=a^{-1}\sec\theta\tan\theta$.

Comment: What's wrong with saying $x - r_1 = r \cos(\theta)$? Is there a way to salvage this?

Comment: You can use that in a parametrization, partnered with say $y-r_2=r\sin\theta$, but it means you're basically taking $X:=x-r_1,\,Y:=y-r_2$ as a new system of Cartesian coordinates, which is the point of my origin-shifting proposal.

Comment: So how do we "un"shift once we're done solving for $r$ with the Cartesian to Polar conversion process and finish the solving?

Comment: That would mean using the _original_ Cartesian coordinates with $x=r\cos\theta,\,y=r\sin\theta$, so the result is nowhere near as neat. If you're genuinely interested in that polar form, the one I've been talking about isn't worth obtaining, as it can't be converted except via a Cartesian intermediate.

Comment: So in general, u-substitution can't help convert from Cartesian to Polar?